# appcompat7 Material DatepickerDialog maxdate problems

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Here is my code

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.basicCalendar)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar mCalStart = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar mCalEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog mDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, null, mCalStart.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalStart.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalStart.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            mCalStart.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            mCalEnd.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
            mDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mCalStart.getTimeInMillis());
            mDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mCalEnd.getTimeInMillis());
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

With this code, I cannot click 8/8, the last day of limited date. 
I tried to change maxdate's limit to another date, but always I couldn't click the last day.

Comment: Just curious if you ever found the solution to this? I am having the same problem. I can't select the last selectable date (even though it shows selectable). The weird thing is, it works just fine on a virtual device, but not my actual phone.